# Combox and LINQ - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to make a LINQ statement that uses what Country the user selects from a combobox and displays the cities that are in the database in a listbox. Attached is what I have so far. There are numerous Countries so using an if statement will not work.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim myQ1 = From X In CustomersDataset.Customers Where

    X.Country = ComboBox1.SelectedItem Select X.City 

    '(X.Country = "France" Select X.City)-only shows city options for France obviously.


    lstCity.DataSource = myQ1.ToList
End Sub
```

Comment: Try X.Country = ComboBox1.SelectedValue

Comment: Still receiving build errors, thank you though

Comment: What is your build error?

Comment: Look at error list on bottom.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments:

    'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':

        Argument matching parameter 'b' cannot convert from 'DataRowView' to 'String'.

Comment: I should be able to help you after you answer this question.  Is the line where it has the error where it says "X.Country = ComboBox1...."?  If somewhere else, please show us that code.

Comment: That is the line that shows an error.

Comment: To make it easier, i will add all the code in my program. It is very short, as it is being used with a database and the form holds most of the info.

Comment: Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CustomersDataSet.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomersDataSet.Customers)


    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim Query1 = From X In CustomersDataSet.Customers Where
X.Country = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
        ListBox1.DataSource = Query1.ToList
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The [ComboBox SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) is of the Object type and is what it is bounded to.  Therefore you have to cast the DataRowView to a String so that the comparison can be made in your linq query:

```
Dim strSelectedItemValue As String = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("ReplaceWithTheColumnNameOfTheCountryField")

Dim myQ1 = From X In CustomersDataset.Customers 
Where X.Country = strSelectedItemValue
Select X.City

lstCity.DataSource = myQ1.ToList
lstCity.DataBind()
```

Comment: How would I get the results to display on a listbox? I tried lstCity.DataSource = myQ1.ToList, however, it does not work with this solution

Comment: I edited the answer to show you need to call .DataBind().  If this helped you, please don't forget to accept this as the answer.

Comment: I still did not come to a solution, as an error with databind occured

Comment: Should probably be posted as another question.  I'm pretty sure the issue "asked about" (no question really) was solved.  If you do ask another question, I would provide error messages and exact line of code of failure.